# bitwise biconditional in C - sum of products not working

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

Why doesn't either of the code snippets achieve biconditional functionality in C?

```
int x = !!((a & b) | (~a & ~b))
```

or
`int x = !!(!!(a & b) | !!(~a & ~b))`

But, the following works: `!((a & ~b) | (~a & b))`

Comment: Can you please explain what "biconditional functionality" means exactly? Please give the exact input, expected result and actual result.

Comment: @kaylum by biconditional, I mean a == b.

Comment: Note that `!((a & ~b) | (~a & b))` is just `!(a^b)`, where `^` is the bitwise XOR operator.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disprove the first two assertions, a simple counter example suffices:

`a=0, b=1` in `int x = !!((a & b) | (~a & ~b))` becomes:

- `int x = !!((0 & 1) | (~0 & ~1));`
- `int x = !!(0 | ~1);`
- `int x = !!~1;`
- `int x = 1;` -> incorrect

The problem with this expression if `!!` is not a bitwise operator. The expression `((a & b) | (~a & ~b))` has all bits set if and only if `a == b`, but `!!` is inappropriate to test this condition. You should instead use `int x = !~((a & b) | (~a & ~b));`

`a=0, b=1` in `int x = !!(!!(a & b) | !!(~a & ~b))` becomes:

- `int x = !!(!!(0 & 1) | !!(~0 & ~1));`
- `int x = !!(!!(0) | !!(~1));`
- `int x = !!(0 | 1);`
- `int x = !!(1);`
- `int x = 1;` -> incorrect

Again, the problem is `!!`. Here it is applied separately to `(a & b)` and `(~a & ~b)`, removing all hope of parallel bit comparison.

For the third expression: `((a & ~b) | (~a & b))` sets each bit in the result to `1` if either the corresponding bit is (`0` in `a` and `1` in `b`) or (`1` in `a` and `0` in `b`). In other words, each bit in the result is set to `1` if and only if the corresponding bits in `a` and `b` differ. If all bits in the result are `0`, then all bits in `a` are identical to the same bit in `b`, hence `a` and `b` are identical. QED.

The assumption here is that `a` and `b` are equal if and only if all their bits are identical. It is true for 2's complement representation used by all modern computers, but not for ancient exotic machines that used ones' complement or sign/magnitude representations.

For these weirdos, only `0` has 2 potential representations but one can find values of `a` and `b` for which the expression `((a & ~b) | (~a & b))` evaluates to an alternative representation of `0` although `a` and `b` are different.

- `1` and `-1` is a counter example for sign/magnitude representation.
- `1` and `-2` is a counter example for ones' complement representation.

Comment: Thanks. All these all equivalent in boolean algebra:  top is SOP form. Is there a theorem, property or corollary as to why this doesn't hold with bit strings?

Comment: @MikeAdams: I expanded the answer with more explanations about why the first two expressions fail to implement the sum of products :)

Comment: Thanks. Is there some rule as to when `!!` doesn't work?

Comment: @MikeAdams: `!!` is the boolean conversion: for an integer expression `e`, `!!e` is equivalent to `e != 0`, which means *any of the bits of `e` is non zero*. Whether it *works* or not depends on what you want to compute.